# Date difference in years in PySpark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, datediff

I come from Pandas background and new to Spark. I have a dataframe which has `id`, `dob`, `age` as columns. I want to get the age of the user from his `dob` (in some cases `age` column is NULL).

```
+----+------+----------+
| id | age  |   dob    |
+----+------+----------+
|  1 | 24   | NULL     |
|  2 | 25   | NULL     |
|  3 | NULL | 1/1/1973 |
|  4 | NULL | 6/6/1980 |
|  5 | 46   |          |
|  6 | NULL | 1/1/1971 |
+----+------+----------+
```

I want a new column which will calculate age from `dob` and current date.

I tried this, but not getting any results from it:

```
df.withColumn("diff", 
              datediff(to_date(lit("01-06-2020")),
                       to_date(unix_timestamp('dob', "dd-MM-yyyy").cast("timestamp")))).show()
```

Comment: can you check my answer too? I used somewhat different approach of getting `month difference` and then divide it to `12`. I believe it is more appropriate to use `months_between` when it comes to year difference. we should use `datediff` only when if you need difference in days

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to compute the date difference and convert the result to years, something like this:

```
df.withColumn('diff', 
    when(col('age').isNull(), 
         floor(datediff(current_date(), to_date(col('dob'), 'M/d/yyyy'))/365.25))\
  .otherwise(col('age'))).show()
```

Which produces:

```
+---+----+--------+----+
| id| age|     dob|diff|
+---+----+--------+----+
|  1|  24|    null|  24|
|  2|  25|    null|  25|
|  3|null|1/1/1973|  47|
|  4|null|6/6/1980|  39|
|  5|  46|    null|  46|
|  6|null|1/1/1971|  49|
+---+----+--------+----+
```

It preserves the `age` column where not null and computes the difference (in days) between `dob` and today where `age` is null. The result is then converted to years (by dividing by 365.25; you may want to confirm this) then `floor`ed.

Answer (score 4):

**I believe it is more appropriate to use `months_between` when it comes to `year difference`. we should use `datediff` only when if you need `difference in days`**

### Approach-

```scala
 val data =
      """
        | id | age  |   dob
        |  1 | 24   |
        |  2 | 25   |
        |  3 |      | 1/1/1973
        |  4 |      | 6/6/1980
        |  5 | 46   |
        |  6 |      | 1/1/1971
      """.stripMargin

    val stringDS = data.split(System.lineSeparator())
      .map(_.split("\\|").map(_.replaceAll("""^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$""", "")).mkString(","))
      .toSeq.toDS()
    val df = spark.read
      .option("sep", ",")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .option("header", "true")
      .csv(stringDS)
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +---+----+--------+
      * |id |age |dob     |
      * +---+----+--------+
      * |1  |24  |null    |
      * |2  |25  |null    |
      * |3  |null|1/1/1973|
      * |4  |null|6/6/1980|
      * |5  |46  |null    |
      * |6  |null|1/1/1971|
      * +---+----+--------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- age: integer (nullable = true)
      * |-- dob: string (nullable = true)
      */
```

### Find age

```scala
  df.withColumn("diff",
      coalesce(col("age"),
      round(months_between(current_date(),to_date(col("dob"), "d/M/yyyy"),true).divide(12),2)
      )
     ).show()

    /**
      * +---+----+--------+-----+
      * | id| age|     dob| diff|
      * +---+----+--------+-----+
      * |  1|  24|    null| 24.0|
      * |  2|  25|    null| 25.0|
      * |  3|null|1/1/1973|47.42|
      * |  4|null|6/6/1980|39.99|
      * |  5|  46|    null| 46.0|
      * |  6|null|1/1/1971|49.42|
      * +---+----+--------+-----+
      */
```

> round it to `0` if you want age in whole number

Answer (score 2):

Using `months_between` like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148704/66362329#62149345), but in a different approach:

- in my table, I don't have `'age'` column yet;
- for rounding to full years I use `.cast('int')`.

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn('age', (F.months_between(current_date(), F.col('dob')) / 12).cast('int'))
```

---

If system date is UTC and your locale is different, a separate date function may be needed:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
def current_local_date():
    return F.from_utc_timestamp(F.current_timestamp(), 'Europe/Riga').cast('date')
df = df.withColumn('age', (F.months_between(current_local_date(), F.col('dob')) / 12).cast('int'))
```